# How can I avoid "$digest already in progress" error in my AngularJS test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing

I'm having a problem with running one of my AngularJS tests in Karma using Chrome. The test works in PhantomJS.

When running the test using Chrome I get the following error:

```
Chrome 46.0.2490 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.18/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
  at C:/dev/unionvms_eu/branches/dev/unionvms-web/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:275
```

**Test:**

```
describe('todoRestService', function() {

    beforeEach(module('todoApp'));

    //MOCK RESOURCE
    beforeEach(function () {
        var mockResource = {
            todo: function() {
                return {
                    update: function(todoDTO, callback) {
                        callback({
                            code : 200,
                            data: {
                                status : 'CLOSED'
                            }
                        });
                    },
                }
            },
        };

        module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('todoRestFactory', mockResource);
        });

    });

    it("updateTodoStatus should send request to backend and return received object", inject(function($rootScope, $log, todoRestService, Todo) {
        var todo = new Todo();
        todo.status = "CLOSED";

        var resolved = false;
        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
            todoRestService.updateTodoStatus(todo).then(function(updatedTodo){
                resolved = true;
                expect(updatedTodo.status).toEqual(todo.status);
            });
        });
        $rootScope.$digest();
        expect(resolved).toBe(true);
    }));

});
```

**The code:**

```
angular.module('todoApp')
    .factory('todoRestFactory',function($resource) {
        return {
            todo : function(){
                return $resource('/app/todo', {}, {
                    update: {method: 'PUT'}
                });
            },
        };
    })
.factory('todoRestService', function($q, $log, todoRestFactory, Todo){

    var updateTodoStatus = function(todo){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        todoRestFactory.todo().update(todo.DTO(), function(response) {
            if(response.code !== 200){
                deferred.reject("Invalid response status");
                return;
            }
            deferred.resolve(Todo.fromDTO(response.data));
        }, function(error) {
            $log.error("Error updating todo status");
            $log.error(error);
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return {
        updateTodoStatus: updateTodoStatus,
    };
});
```

If I remove `$rootScope.$digest();` from the test, the error goes away but the last assertion will fail. How can I make the test work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if $digest already started.
You can do this by

```
 if(!$scope.$$phase) {
 //do smth here
}
```

Comment: I tried wrapping `$rootScope.$digest();` in the unit test in this but I still get the same error.

Comment: $rootScope.apply have to fire $digest by itself. But you can try to use  $applyAsync() instead of $apply.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: If i am not mistaken you are dealing with like async methods. Best way to force $digest on them is to call $asyncApply on the scope. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is 3 way to solve this:

- Write a safeApply function that look like this:

  ```
  $scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
    var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
    if(phase === '$apply' || phase === '$digest') {
      if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
        fn();
      }
    } else {
      this.$apply(fn);
    }
  };
  ```
- You can also use the [safeApply](https://github.com/yearofmoo/AngularJS-Scope.SafeApply) component

In code :

```
$scope.$safeApply();
```

- call the `$apply` inside a `$timeout` :

  ```
  $timeout($scope.$apply, 0);
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really understand what you mean. Where should I put `$scope.$safeApply();`? And where should I call $timeout?

Comment: In your code :
`       var todo = new Todo();
        todo.status = "CLOSED";

        var resolved = false;
        $rootScope.$safeApply(function(){
            todoRestService.updateTodoStatus(todo).then(function(updatedTodo){
                resolved = true;
                expect(updatedTodo.status).toEqual(todo.status);
            });
        });
        expect(resolved).toBe(true);`

Comment: In a more common way, just replace all your $apply by $safeApply !

Comment: Did you replace all the $apply by $safeApply?
You should remove your $rootScope.$digest(); too! The $apply make the digest.

Comment: I replaced apply with safeApply and removed digest() in the unit test but it didn't work. In the service, there is no apply at all.

Comment: And by using the timeout like this:
`
$timeout(function(){
      $rootScope.$apply(function(){
            todoRestService.updateTodoStatus(todo).then(function(updatedTodo){
                resolved = true;
                expect(updatedTodo.status).toEqual(todo.status);
            });
        });
}, 0);
`

Comment: When using the timeout (like you've described) I get the test to run but the last assertion fails since `resolved`still is `false`.

Comment: Did you put the following statement inside the timeout? : expect(resolved).toBe(true);